# Do something IF at least one item does not have a specific style applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a fiddle for referrence https://jsfiddle.net/mc6jqtzr/

I need to be able to populate the innerHTML of `#date` with some content only IF at least one `option` in the select list above DOES NOT have a style applied (in this case the display property).

e.g. the last `option` does not have a style applied, so the `#date` should get populated.

```js
var date = $("#date");


// Show the date only if there are open spots
if ($('.js-check-in-times option:visible').length === 0) {
  date.html('');  
} else {
  date.html('Working now.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="check-in__select js-check-in-times" id="time" name="AptTime" required="" aria-required="true" aria-label="times filter">
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:15:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="display: none;">08:15 AM</option>
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:30:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="display: none;">08:30 AM</option>
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:45:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="">08:45 AM</option>
</select>

<div id="date" style="font-size: 24px; color: red; font-family: sans-serif;"></div>
```

Comment: if you can, remove the `option` from the DOM instead of 'hiding' it

Comment: @andymccullough yes, but this is can not be done on my side for now.

Comment: doesnt look like you can use `:visible` on `option`s - https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ "All option elements are considered hidden, regardless of their selected state"

Comment: `$('.js-check-in-times option:visible').css('display')`

Comment: absolutely not ideal, but given your current method of `display: none` - this works - `if ($('.js-check-in-times option[style="display: none;"]').length === 0)`

Comment: @andymccullough , thank you! If you want, form an answer, so that I can select it.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through options to get count of option which are hidden then check if the total hidden and total option are same or not depending on this show your message.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var date = $("#date");
var count = 0;
$('.js-check-in-times option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
    count++;
  }
})
console.log(count)
// Show the date only if there are open spots
if ($('.js-check-in-times option').length === count) {
  date.html('');
} else {
  date.html('Working now.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="check-in__select js-check-in-times" id="time" name="AptTime" required="" aria-required="true" aria-label="times filter">
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:15:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="display: none;">08:15 AM</option>
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:30:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="display: none;">08:30 AM</option>
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:45:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="">08:45 AM</option>
</select>

<div id="date" style="font-size: 24px; color: red; font-family: sans-serif;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- you can select all the options then get style attribute and check

> Check if style is empty

```
var date = $("#date");
var sel = $("#time");
var opts = sel.find("option");

for(var opt of opts) {
    if($(opt).attr("style") !== undefined && $(opt).attr("style") === "") {
        date.html("There's Element Haven't Style");
    } else {
        date.html('Working now.');
    }
}
```

> Check if just the visible options and it's style

```
var date = $("#date");
var sel = $("#time");
var opts = sel.find("option");

for(var opt of opts) {
    if($(opt).css("display") !== "none" && $(opt).attr("style") !== undefined && $(opt).attr("style") === "") {
        date.html("There's Element Haven't Style");
    } else {
        date.html('Working now.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter `options` based on the value of `style` attribute.
If style attribute is absent, compare with `null` instead of `''`

```js
var date = $("#date");

// Show the date only if there are open spots
var optionsWithEmptyStyle = $('.js-check-in-times option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr('style') === '';
});

if (optionsWithEmptyStyle.length === 0) {
  date.html('');
} else {
  date.html('Working now.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="check-in__select js-check-in-times" id="time" name="AptTime" required="" aria-required="true" aria-label="times filter">
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:15:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="display: none;">08:15 AM</option>
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:30:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="display: none;">08:30 AM</option>
  <option value="2021-07-28T08:45:00.000-04:00" data-group="2021-07-28" style="">08:45 AM</option>
</select>

<div id="date" style="font-size: 24px; color: red; font-family: sans-serif;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple, yet working solution:

```
if ($('.js-check-in-times option[style=""]').length > 0)
```

This seems to do the trick.

Much thanks to `andy mccullough` for pointing out the [visibility limitations](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) for select options.